# Resize images to match CSS

Tags: images

I was wondering is there any way to automatically resize images to match the dimensions set by the user.
What I mean is:

1. User creates a post and he puts an image with id="my_img" and src /my_path/my_img.jpg. He adds css #my_img {width: 310px;}
2. The plugin matches these and it generates copy of my_img.jpg with dimensions set by CSS and name ex my_img_310px.jpg.
3. The plugin changes img src to /my_path/my_img_310px.jpg
4. Every image in every resolution is transmitted in perfect dimensions and page speed is awesome.

I couldn't find any plugins with such a functionality and everywhere I look I read images shall be uploaded in matching dimensions.

Do you know any way of achieving this or why is it impossible?

Comment: Likely possible, but is it a _good_ workflow? Why should user micromanage dimensions? How will it resist dimensions set to least fitting into design possible?

Comment: there are other reasons as well, but if for every resize of the window you will ask the server to generate a new image, the server will die quickly.